# How to create crystal report to list parent and child records?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, crystal-reports

i'm using linq to sql in .Net 2010 project, i'm preparing the data in a list to load the data in the rpt file.

the parent table (passport):

```
ID   name   passport_number

1    Donnie 123456

2    Monica 789797

3    John   587123
```

The child table (passport_addons):

```
ID     parent_id   addon_name

1      2           Bob

2      2           Beverly
```

I want the rpt file to show the list of all the passport, and the passport_addons records below them if exists, for example:

```
ID      NAME     PASSPORT NUMBER

1       Donnie   123456

2       Monica   789797

        Bob

        Beverly

3       John     587123
```

is that possible? and if it's possible, how to achieve it using linq to sql?

Comment: I don't know about linq to SQL, but it is possible using Crystal connecting to SQL using ODBC/OLEDB, etc.  To do that: Add the two tables with a left outer join from passport to passport_addons on passport.id = passport_addons.parent_id.  Put the addons information in the detail band and then insert a group on passport.id.  Optionally, conditionally suppress the details when parent_id is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there are limited number of addons on the passport, maximum is 5.

I've added 10 columns to the passport table like this:
addon_1
addon_1_birthday
addon_2
addon_2_birthday
addon_3
addon_3_birthday
addon_4
addon_4_birthday
addon_5
addon_5_birthday

May be it's not the best solution, but it has satisfied the requirement, by using only 1 table for the Crystal Report.

And I hope that could help other people having same issue.